# Create & Return Token in Serializer

Tags: python, django

Currently having difficulties returning a token in my registration view.

How Can I fix this so that UserSerializer's create can return a token and username?

View.py

```
@permission_classes([AllowAny])
class UserCreate(generics.CreateAPIView):
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
```

Serializers.py

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username', 'password')
        extra_kwargs = {'password': {'write_only': True}}

    def create(self, validated_data):
        password = validated_data.pop('password')
        user = User(**validated_data)
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save()
        token, _ = Token.objects.get_or_create(user=user)
        return Response(
            {
                'username': validated_data['username'],
                'token': token.key,
            },
            status=HTTP_200_OK
        )
```

Error

```
AttributeError: Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field `username` on serializer `UserSerializer`.
The serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the `Response` instance.
Original exception text was: 'Response' object has no attribute 'username'.
[13/Nov/2020 20:26:44] "POST /account/register HTTP/1.1" 500 120116
```

Comment: The error says `username` is missing from data.

Comment: Here is my request: `http post http://127.0.0.1:8000/account/register username='test37' password='password'`

Comment: Put `print(validated_data)` in your serializer and see if has all the required fields.

Comment: {
    "username": "test40"
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up putting it in the Serializer:

````
class UserCreate(generics.CreateAPIView):
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer

    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        self.perform_create(serializer)
        token, created = Token.objects.get_or_create(user=serializer.instance)
        return Response({'token': token.key, 'username': serializer.instance.username}, status=HTTP_201_CREATED)```
````